# How to create a list of class names and iterate throught the static methoc in it?

Tags: java, list, class, static, iterator

I have list of classes:

`List<Class<?>> = Array.asList(ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD);`

each of them has a static method `staticMethod(byte[] bytes)`

How can I iterate through this list of classes and calling the staticMethod?

Comment: Do you know how to do it for a single class?

Comment: You'll want the `getMethod` method of the `Class` class, and the `invoke` method of the `Method` class.  The javadocs for both those methods are in the usual place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent your List like lambda expressions for your static methods.

```java
        List<Consumer<byte[]>> functionsList = Arrays.asList(ClassA::staticMethod, ClassB::staticMethod);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        functionsList.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(bytes));
```

Full code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Consumer<byte[]>> functionsList = Arrays.asList(ClassA::staticMethod, ClassB::staticMethod);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        functionsList.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(bytes));
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    public static void staticMethod(byte[] bytes) {
        System.out.println("ClassA.staticMethod(byte[] bytes)" + Arrays.toString(bytes));
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    public static void staticMethod(byte[] bytes) {
        System.out.println("ClassB.staticMethod(byte[] bytes)" + Arrays.toString(bytes));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ClassA.staticMethod(byte[] bytes)[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ClassB.staticMethod(byte[] bytes)[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**EDIT:**
Example for methods with return value:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        List<Function<byte[], String>> functionsList = Arrays.asList(ClassA::staticMethodWithReturn, ClassB::staticMethodWithReturn);
        functionsList.forEach(function -> {
            String returnValue = function.apply(bytes);
         }
        );
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    public static String staticMethodWithReturn(byte[] bytes) {
        return "";
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    public static String staticMethodWithReturn(byte[] bytes) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the static method is not void and I need to consume the return value off it?

Comment: I added an example for the methods with return value.